# How to load pdf.worker.js in spring boot project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, pdf

I am using react-pdf for view pdf.i build front end and added with spring boot project. now pdf is not viewed .how to solve this problem. I attached below error as a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: share more detail.

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan pdf.worker.js file how to set or config with project .it is saying the pdf.worker.js path is wrong. how to set that path spring boot.